# PHP - PayPal Parallel Payment NVP popup

Tags: javascript, php, paypal

i use the script checkout.js for render the PayPal Button on my web page.
When i click on the button, a popup is open for process the payment.

Once the payment done, the popup doesn't close. She stay open with the success page on my website.

How to close her automatically ?

Edit: Exemple here: [github](https://github.com/eoxia-jimmy/parralel-paypal).

More: When the payment is not parralel, the popup is close after the payment. But in my case, the payment is parralel.

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: U can see an example on [link](https://github.com/eoxia-jimmy/parralel-paypal)